# How can I send data in Jetpack compose between screens?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation

How can I send surveyToken here to ResultScreen?

```
surveyScreen(
    moveToResult = { surveyToken ->
        navController.navigateToResult(surveyToken)
    }
)
```

And here's the navigateToResult function.

```
const val resultRoute = "result_route"

fun NavController.navigateToResult(surveyToken: String, navOptions: NavOptions? = null) {
    this.navigate("$resultRoute/$SURVEY_TOKEN?=$surveyToken", navOptions)
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
fun NavGraphBuilder.resultScreen(deviceDisplayState: DeviceDisplayState, moveToOrder: () -> Unit, moveToBack: () -> Unit) {
    composable(route = resultRoute) {
        ResultRoute(deviceDisplayState, moveToOrder, moveToBack, hiltViewModel(LocalContext.current as MainActivity))
    }
}
```

And here's the ViewModel that I want to get the value.

```
@HiltViewModel
class ResultViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    val snackBarMonitor: SnackBarMonitor
) : ViewModel() {
    private val surveyToken: String = checkNotNull(savedStateHandle[SURVEY_TOKEN])
}
```

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/result_route/survey_token?=711d28d33d0fd880459108da5aeb819fce94948f49bdbed20117a27c7109 } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination={NavGraph(0x22fb6594) route=entry_graph startDestination={Destination(0x2395568f) route=entry_route}}
this error.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely

```
 this.navigate("$resultRoute?$SURVEY_TOKEN=$surveyToken", navOptions)
```

But you might want to include the route definitions next time for more accurate answers.

Comment: What do you mean by `route definitions`? And I changed as you said and I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required value was null.` exception in ViewModel. I added the question. Could you please check?

Comment: The `composable("[route definition]"` where you actually declare what your requested arguments are.